# Raspberry Pi, Mono, and Trig Functions

Tags: c#, mono, arm, raspberry-pi, trigonometry

I was experimenting with using the raspberry pi as a synthesizer and ran into some really peculiar behavior. I made a really simple sine wave oscillator to test and noticed that the oscillator is maxing out the cpu.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
namespace OSCTest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            System.Threading.Timer timer = new Timer(process, null, 1000, 1000);
            Console.WriteLine ("Running.");
            Console.ReadLine ();
            timer.Dispose();
        }
        public static void process(object state)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 44100; i++)
            {
                float j;
                j = (float)Math.Sin(2f * Math.PI * i * 1000f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This simple program completely maxes out the RPi's cpu and repeatedly creates threads to handle the incoming timer tick events.

I knew that trig functions are considered to be rather expensive compared to simple math functions so I took out the sin calculation and ran the program again.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
namespace OSCTest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            System.Threading.Timer timer = new Timer(process, null, 1000, 1000);
            Console.WriteLine ("Running.");
            Console.ReadLine ();
            timer.Dispose();
        }
        public static void process(object state)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 44100; i++)
            {
                float j;
                j = (float)(2f * Math.PI * i * 1000f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Pi doesn't even blink when running the above example, quite literally, top reports 0.0% cpu usage on the executable.

So my question is, what is causing the extreme slowdown? Is it the RPi being unable to compute sin well? Is it something specific to the mono runtime on the pi? Is it something even deeper that I'm not understanding?

Edit: reformmated code examples.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the code formatting was off, I just made the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider the fact that Timer invokes `process` function every 1000 ms and invokes can overlap if `process` function is too slow to finish in 1000 ms.

This can bloat the CPU with excessive number of threads and make the system sluggish.

You can put a flag check to `process` function to ensure it is executed by one thread at any given point of time.